# How to change the value for a specific cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview

Good evening! Can you please tell me how to make it possible to save like/unlike values for each cell? I use `UserDefaults`, but so far I can only set the value for all cells at once. I understand that I need to configure somehow this moment in cellForRowAt , but I don’t understand how to do it.

My ViewController:

```
struct Likes {
    let id: Int
    let isLike: Bool
}

final class ListTicketsViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var likesDict: [Int:Bool] = [:]
    var likesArray: [Likes] = []

...

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! ListTicketsModulCell
        let ticket = tickets[indexPath.row]
        cell.configure(with: ticket)
        
        likesDict.updateValue(ButtonSettings.isButtonTapped, forKey: indexPath.row)
        
        for (key, value) in likesDict {
            likesArray.append(Likes(id: key, isLike: value))
        }
        
        let cellLike = likesArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.isButtonPressed = cellLike.isLike
        
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBlue
        return cell
    }
```

My cell:

```
class ListTicketsModulCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    var isButtonPressed: Bool = false
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        
        isButtonPressed = ButtonSettings.isButtonTapped
        
    }

...

@objc func likeButtonPressed() {
        if isButtonPressed == false {
            likeButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "heart.fill"), for: .normal)
            likeButton.tintColor = .red
            ButtonSettings.isButtonTapped = true
        } else if isButtonPressed == true {
            likeButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "heart"), for: .normal)
            likeButton.tintColor = .white
            ButtonSettings.isButtonTapped = false
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Answer (score 0):

So as I see it a possible solution here would be to pass a closure to the cell which the cell will call when the button is tapped.
Something like this:

```
struct Likes {
    let id: Int
    let isLike: Bool
}

final class ListTicketsViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var likesDict: [Int:Bool] = [:]
    var likesArray: [Likes] = []

...

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! ListTicketsModulCell
        let ticket = tickets[indexPath.row]
        cell.configure(with: ticket)
        
        cell.didTapLike = { isLiked in 
            // Do what you want when the like changed
            // Add you can capture the indexPath here as well
        }
        let cellLike = likesArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.isButtonPressed = cellLike.isLike
        
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBlue
        return cell
    }
```

```
class ListTicketsModulCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    var isButtonPressed: Bool = false
    var didTapLike: ((Bool) -> ())?
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        
        isButtonPressed = ButtonSettings.isButtonTapped
        
    }

...

@objc func likeButtonPressed() {
        if !isButtonPressed {
            likeButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "heart.fill"), for: .normal)
            likeButton.tintColor = .red
            ButtonSettings.isButtonTapped = true
        } else {
            likeButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "heart"), for: .normal)
            likeButton.tintColor = .white
            ButtonSettings.isButtonTapped = false
        }
        didTapLike?(isButtonPressed)
    }
```

The code may not work as I just drafted it here but I hope you get the general idea. Don't hesitate to comment!